# Spring Kafka- Prevent consumer to connect Kafka topic during build in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I did `autoStartup(false)` on the container factory but not sure where I should inject `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`.

I don't want consumer to connect at the time of build. It should connect `Kafka` topic after spring boot application start completely.

Comment: Please add sample code of what you have tried

Comment: I am trying to start spring kafka consumer after Spring boot application start completely and wanted to place this piece of code  try {
            log.info("Starting kafka listener container......");
            kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.info("Exception while Starting kafka listener container: ",e);
        }

Comment: yes you can do this inside `kafkaListener` method, to get `ListenerContainer` you should have `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` instance, so autowiring `Registry` will helps you

Answer (score 5):

You should inject the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` in class with `KafkaListener` annotated method because from the docs

> The listener containers created for @KafkaListener annotations are not beans in the application context. Instead, they are registered with an infrastructure bean of type KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry

so by using this `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` instance you can manage the life cycle of containers start/stop [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle)

Example :

```
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

   ...

 @KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = "myTopic", autoStartup = "false")
 public void listen(...) { ... }

 ...
registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start();
```

Comment: I have added above mentioned code but getting error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another endpoint is already registered with id 'myContainerId'

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another endpoint is already registered with id 'myContainerId'
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:153) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]

Comment: `myContainerId` is this your groupid? remove this from `kafkaListener` annotation, and also update complete code

Comment: Group id is different.        @KafkaListener(id="myContainerId", topics = "${kafka.consumer.topic}", groupId = "${kafka.consumer.group.id.config}",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")

Comment: public void receive(@Payload List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> customerMarketingAttributesRecords,
                        Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        try {
            kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myContainerId").start();

Comment: Please update consumerconfig class and consumerclass code in question

Comment: can you remove `@Bean` annotation on `public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` and try again

Comment: If I remove bean spring kafka wont work..getting broker unavailable message.

Comment: actually error message says bean with 'myContainerId' already registered, which means either remove `@Bean` annotation or `@service` or `@component` on top of service class, make sure you registered one consumer with that id

Comment: and also you can add `autoStartup = "false"` in `@kafkaListenet`

Comment: I did mentioned change but now getting error "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available"